# TextView cannot be cast to EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

First time posting a question to this site so I might make some mistakes!

I'm new to programming and getting the following error when running an application in Android Studio:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

The code that's causing this issue is

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
```

I've tried to delete the R.java files and clean the project but it didn't work, any help solving the problem would be greatly appreciated :)

I can add any other files or relevant code that might be a factor in the problem.

Edit: After changing the code from text view to edit text I'm getting a new error.

Logcat:

```
08-03 20:08:04.413  29662-29662/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp/com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp.NoteEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp.NoteEditorActivity.onCreate(NoteEditorActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The xml file, activity_note_editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/noteText"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The file that's giving the error, NoteEditorActivity:

```
public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity {

        private NoteItem note;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);




            Intent intent = this.getIntent();
            note = new NoteItem();
            note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
            note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
            et.setText(note.getText());
            et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
        }
    }
```

Mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import data.NoteItem;
import data.NotesDataSource;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private NotesDataSource datasource;

    List<NoteItem> notesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();

    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList=datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this,R.layout.list_item_layout,notesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_create) {
            createNote();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote() {
        NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("key",note.getText());
        startActivityForResult(intent,1001);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `TextView` with id `noteText` in your xml file?

Comment: Try to clean the project and build it again.If that doesn't work It might be that you have a textview with and id of noteText in you xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your xml, 
change

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/noteText"
.../>
```

to

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/noteText"
.../>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

You didn't put 'text' in the intent. :)

Try changing

```
intent.putExtra("key",note.getKey());
intent.putExtra("key",note.getText());
```

to

```
intent.putExtra("key",note.getKey());
intent.putExtra("text",note.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed the code and I'm getting a new error, Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp/com.example.toshiba.notetakingapp.NoteEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please edit your question with errors  in log cat and your java codes.

Comment: Ok, I added the xml file and the file that was giving the error

Comment: Please post the full log cat. I want to know which line has the error.

Comment: I think it's because there is not Extras in the intent. Please check whether you put extras or not.

Comment: I added the file where the intent is declared, I put in the extras at the bottom.

Comment: I see. You didn't put 'text'. You just put two 'key'. :)

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't notice that! It's working perfectly now, thanks for the help, I'm sorry it was such a stupid mistake! :)

Comment: The nullpointer is definitely because te extras don't exist  - to test this just set the text on your editText to any strings I.e. "test" and run the app, if it doesn't crash then it definitely points to null values in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

If the view that contains the TextEdit is not showing up (In other words it is not displayed on the screen) it will throw a null pointer. Is the XML that contains this EditText called activity_note_editor?

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that, the xml file with the edit text is activity_note_editor.

Comment: You might see what is at line 33 of your activity because that is what is causing the crash

Comment: Line 33 is: et.setSelection(note.getText().length());, I don't know why that would give an error

Answer (score 0):

If all the solutions fail to work. Then kindly do check if you were using TextView or Plain Text. Using TextView and doing so might be the reason.